# Правильное позиционирование элемента

Tags: html, css

Делаю сайт с постами и комментариями, выглядеть пост должен так: title, текст поста, комментарии. Комментарии должны находиться на определённом расстоянии от друг друга и от текста поста. (Позиционирование тайтла и текста поста - absolute.)
Но когда я пишу "margin-top 20px" в блоке комментариев, то тайтл с текстом тоже сдвигается. Вот код.

```php
<?php 
 $id = $_GET['id'];
  $mysql = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '','users');
  $tred = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `treds` WHERE `id` = '$id'");
  $tredAr = $tred->fetch_assoc();
  if($tredAr == ""){
    echo "Пост не найден";
    exit();
  }
  $commy = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `comments`WHERE `PostID` = '$id'");

  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gayathri|Oswald:60&display=swap&subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
       <span class="title"><?php echo $tredAr['title']; ?></span>
       <span class="text"><?php echo $tredAr['body']; ?></span>
       <?php
       while ($com = mysqli_fetch_assoc($commy)) {
         ?>
         <div class="comment">

          <a href="/profiles/user.php?id=<?php echo $com['autorID'];?>"><?php echo $com['autor']; ?></a><br>
          <span><?php echo $com['text']; ?></span><br>

           </div>        <?php
        }
         ?>

  </body>
  </html>
```

```css
.title{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 40px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
.text{
    margin-top: 70px;
        position: absolute;
    font-size: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-family: 'Gayathri', sans-serif;
}
.comment{

    margin-top: 110px;
    font-family: 'Gayathri', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю лучше будет если ты предоставишь сюда уже сгенерированный HTML код, то будет легче найти ошибку и исправить

Comment: @Фёдор, покажите css. Позиционирование элементов происходит именно там.

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, что стоит попробовать сделать два блока - первый блок содержит title и body поста, а во втором находятся комментарии. Приведу простой пример такой вёрстки.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #000;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
}

.post_content {
  max-width: 1100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.post_comm_wrap {
  max-width: 1100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.add_new_comm {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.input_class {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 4px;
}

.comm_block {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.comm_block span {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="content_wrapper">
    
    <div class="post_content">
    
      <h1>Какой-то заголовок</h1>
      
      <p>Какой-то огромный, очень увлекательный и полезный текст вашей статьи</p>
      
    </div>

    <div class="post_comm_wrap">
      
      <div class="add_new_comm">
        
        <form method="post">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Введите Ваш комментарий" class="input_class">
          <input type="submit" class="input_class">
        </form>
        
      </div>
      
      <div class="comm_block">
        
        <span>Имя пользователя</span>
        
        <p>Текст комментария</p>
        
      </div>
      
      <div class="comm_block">
        
        <span>Имя пользователя</span>
        
        <p>Текст комментария</p>
        
      </div>
      
      <div class="comm_block">
        
        <span>Имя пользователя</span>
        
        <p>Текст комментария</p>
        
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </div>

</body>
```